# Swing GUI Designer

Tags: java, swing, reflection

So I am making this project where I need to insert into a JPanel container different types of Swing components (like a JButton, JTextArea etc). My main frame looks like this: [image: Main frame]

Basically I have a text are where a user inputs what he needs inserted (a Button for example) and the component appears in the JPanel. This is achieved dynamically using reflection. I have a method that looks like this:

```
enter code here
JComponent createComponent(String compName)
{
    try {
        Class<?> clazz=Class.forName("javax.swing.J"+compName);
        JComponent jComponent=(JComponent) clazz.newInstance(); 
        jComponent.setBounds(lastClick.x, lastClick.y, 100, 32);
        snapPanel.add(jComponent);
        mover.register(jComponent);
        snapPanel.revalidate();
        return  jComponent;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I need done now is the following: after I click on a component I need for its properties to be displayed in the right hand side Jpanel, where I have created a JTable. And not only do I need the properties to be displayed, I need to be able to modify some of them, like the size.

I thought of using this library http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/ to import the componets properties into the table, but I have not been successful. What I think the logic should be is: after this step:

Class clazz=Class.forName("javax.swing.J"+compName);

I need to take clazz and reflect it into the Jtable somehow. I am new to this reflection api and don't know how to continue. I also don't have much experience constructing a default DefaultTableModel  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would probably be better to use reflection to find all classes in the `javax.swing` package that extend Component instead of creating them from some string value.

Comment: The "user" specifies in the text area near the add button what Components wants inserted. I know it's not ideal, but this is how my task was formulated..

Comment: You could read all the methods of a class, basically you're looking for "getXxx", "setXxx" and "isXxx" patterns

Comment: **Much** better not to use a JTextField which is error prone -- what are you doing to do if the class name has a typo? and instead offer a finite selection with a JComboBox.

Comment: Yes a JComboBox would have been better, but my teacher wants a Text field, so I comply. I will put some exception handling for the Text Field after I finish the project. As for reading the method and looking for patterns sound like a good idea. Maybe I will try it

Comment: The teacher wants you to make yet another (bloody) GUI designer? And one using `null` layouts? They should be tarred, feathered and run out of town..

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: It could be worse.  The teacher could have asked prometheus21 to create the GUI designer using the same GUI designer.  :-)